# Retorno de mensagem usando declare?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou precisando fazer uma verificação de uma variável no `MySQL` semelhante ao do `SQLSERVER`. onde o eu verifico retorno em uma variável na própria mensagem do banco
exemplo no `SQLSERVER` faço assim:

```
DECLARE @nome VARCHAR(20) = 'NOME'
PRINT @Nome;
```

ao rodar esse código o banco de dados me retorna: NOME.

Porem não estou conseguindo fazer isso no `MySQL`

Comment: Tenta usar SET no lugar de DECLARE.

Comment: @KayoBruno "no lugar" acho que não é possível, se trocar o `declare` por `set` não vai funcionar, talvez usar um `set` depois do `declare` foi o que vc quis dizer?

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

O `MySQL` não possui `print`.

Ao invés disso faça um `SELECT` da sua variável:

```
SET @nome = 'NOME';    
SELECT @nome;
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente...obrigado

Comment: @user143412 não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita